# Twitter Card on Twitter with Large Image Disappears After a Week or So

Tags: twitter, open-graph-protocol, twitter-card, twitter-integration

I let users upload urls to share on twitter and they get `twitter:image` as a large image card. They are fine at first but after a while(week or so) they disappear and look like the twitter card below. How would I go about fixing this? They work on mobile but not on web, is this not fixable but normal behavior from twitter? My meta tags seem to be correct and are below?

`<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://d3k6n5v1u6h8v8.cloudfront.net/6c6f26e76f5f71aed1d362117296d314.jpeg?9dljqfhf6h">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@CV_Social">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Arcadia Biosciences Advances Hemp Operations with Archipelago Ventures">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="DAVIS, Calif., Oct. 15, 2019 /PRNewswire/ -- Arcadia Biosciences, Inc. (Nasdaq: RKDA), a leader in science-based approaches to enhancing the quality and...">`

[image: Large image disapears]